# Removing some bad characters from string that is URL in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a very simple question about php.

Imagine i have this string that is containing a URL :

```
$string = "http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050/%D8%AA%DA%A9%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B4-%D9%88-%D9%85%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B8%D9%85-%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C";
```

I want to delete the bad chars like :

```
%D8%AA%DA%A9%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B4-%D9%88-%D9%85%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B8%D9%85-%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C
```

So i need this :

```
$string = "http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050/";
```

How can i do it with PHP ?

I wanted to use some code to delete them like preg match , but it return bad url to me and deleted some more things.

Comment: "Bad chars"? Why are they "bad"? You are almost certainly thinking about this the wrong way, as that is a valid URL.

Comment: @Jon they are not valid with my work, they are persian chars and i want to delete them all from a url .

Comment: What if they were not persian chars? What about the `-`s in there, which are not persian chars? How do you even know you can remove them without a problem in the general case? You don't. And unless **all** the URLs you are ever going to see look exactly like this (in which case you should have mentioned it), there is not enough information here to produce an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Jon You are such observant guy :) can u please check my comment on answeres ? do u have any solution ?

Comment: No. If the question were properly specified I might be able to attempt a solution. But as it stands I don't even know what I would be trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not `bad`, those are just encoded characters. However for your format you can do

```
 if(substr($string,-1)!="/")     // Updated after your comment
     echo substr($string,0,strrpos($string,'/')+1);
 else
    echo $string;
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/7JVoJ8fp)**

**[New Fiddle](http://codepad.org/RZSuwxI5)**

Comment: a problem, if the string is this `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050/` so i will have this : `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/`, how to get that `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050` again ?

Comment: Ok see the update with a little trick, Remember this will only work if the format of your url remains the same as you have mentioned

Comment: Tnx dear its ok, but a little problem again is that string must have / at end :-?

Comment: Ofcourse, you asked for it yourself. Read your comment above :) However if you want you can add a check for it too and i'm so sorry but I wont keep adding code to the answer more, you can do the little bit yourself :)

Comment: Ok thanx for your help dear Hanky , it will be solved just by a IF statement :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *URL Encoded* version. If you just need till the `news/id`, you can use `substr()` to get the last `/`s location and remove others.

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "/") + 1)
```

This returns you the below output:

```
"http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050/"
```

Comment: a problem, if the string is this `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050/` so i will have this : `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/`, how to get that `http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/428050` again ?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're attempting to do is to gather the text from the http through the last last slash, then the preceding code is an excellent choice (substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "/") + 1) ). Does that solve your question, or do you need something different?